# SceneKit can't load the dae, the geotery is nil

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, collada

There is the [dae A can't be load](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1noU9dwS-HsAgyR2AJK8MHC_Rs5_p663O), and I don't know why I can't load it. And it can't be preview in the finder and the Xcode. But it can be load by other software in the window. What is the problem with that dae.

And that [dae B](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HFNi87_QWa5XkyIWH8CQiGIURYjMG5Tu) can load, the different between then is that the "dae B" have not use blend shape. But I must to use it...

I can't find any geotery in it,
[image: dae A in the Xcode]
but it should have.

There is any way to fix it?

Comment: Are these DAE files part of your Xcode project? Are they compiled in to your app bundle? Or are you loading them at runtime from a web server or other external source?

Comment: @robmayoff yes,they compiled in to my app bundle.

Comment: How did you create the DAE files?

Comment: If you are exporting the DAE files from Maya, please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070062/scenekit-keyed-blend-shape-animation-imported-from-collada-dae-file-created).